# just wanna know how to change the CAPTCHA shape

Tags: recaptcha

I’ve asked this question in the mailpoet plugin support forum and I didn’t get no help, they said it’s not related to mailpoet so plz guys I need help with it

i just wanna change the shape of this google recaptcha v2 on my mailpoet forms ( a wordpress plugin used for email lists and newsletters )
it looks like this
https://i.ibb.co/VW0VSnB/Screenshot-5.png

its like a square shape and i dont like it like that, i wanna make it look like more of a rectangle, horizontally taller (like any other normal captcha) so it would look kinda the same as the fields above
kinda like this exactly
https://wpforms.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/reCaptcha-checkbox.png

thank you

Answer (score 1):

recaptcha won't let you change the shape. If you do anything in JavaScript to affect the shape, it'll look to recaptcha like it's been tampered with so it'll think it's a bot visiting the page and not a real user.

Have you considered using recaptcha v2 invisible (https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible) or go all in on recaptcha enterprise? The enterprise version offers way better features and has a pretty decent free usage allowance.